# Objective-c: after ios 11 update black status bar in swrevealcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar, ios11

I'm working on an app. Before the ios 11 update, it worked fine. But after updating to ios 11 and updating XCode, I'm struggling with a bug. I have a side menu using the SWRevealController framework: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController.

After updating to ios 11, it looked like this:

[after ios 11 update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQ2W.png)

There is something wrong with the status bar. It used to be blue, like the rest. I cannot see the text in the statusbar(like the time), but I can see the green battery when I place the whole menu over the screen. As you can see, the other viewcontroller is working fine (just like the whole app). Only the menu is problematic. After doing some debugging, I think the self.navigationController.navigationBar is not heigh enough.

What is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I did not. I found a way around it. I changed the background of some view in the SWRevealController (can't remember which one exactly) to the same blue color. It's a bit dirty, but I couldn't find another way.

Comment: Yeah.  That's the only workaround I see too.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an open cordova bug first recorded [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12886) in June 2017.

The fix described there worked in my case:

> The pure-HTML way to fix this is to add `viewport-fit=cover` to the `meta viewport` tag.

---

Another way to fix it:

`[[webView scrollView] setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior: UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];`